# Concatenate Columns in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, concat

I have a stored procedure which returns a weekly result from input parameters `start date` and `end date`. I am getting multiple rows in the result.

Requirement: I want to add the results of columns in a single column. Below is my final query. From this I want to concatenate the result:

```
SET @sqlText = 
    N'SELECT ['+REPLACE(@columns,',','],[') + ']' +
    ' 
    FROM dbo.timesheet 
    WHERE
        month ='''+ @strMonth+''' 
        AND [Task ID] IN
        (
            SELECT TaskID 
            FROM ManageTasks 
            WHERE
                TeamMemberUserID ='+  Cast(@UserID AS VARCHAR(max)) +
        ')'

--Here I want to add the columns result and need to show as single column

PRINT @sqlText
EXEC (@sqlText)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **FOR XML PATH**

Sample from [TSQL – Concatenate Rows using FOR XML PATH() - **sqlandme.com**](http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/)

```
SELECT      CAT.Name AS [Category],
            STUFF((    SELECT ',' + SUB.Name AS [text()]
                        — Add a comma (,) before each value
                        FROM Production.ProductSubcategory SUB
                        WHERE
                        SUB.ProductCategoryID = CAT.ProductCategoryID
                        FOR XML PATH('') — Select it as XML
                        ), 1, 1, '' )
                        — This is done to remove the first character (,)
                        — from the result
            AS [Sub Categories]
FROM  Production.ProductCategory CAT
```

**Without FOR XML PATH**

[image]

**With FOR XML PATH**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a task for the presentation layer and not something that should not be done using SQL Server...

Having said that, you can use an undocumented side-effect like this:

```
DECLARE @MyConcatString VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @MyConcatString = @MyConcatString + name+ ',' FROM sys.objects
PRINT @MyConcatString
```

To concatenate the `name` from all rows in `sys.objects` into one column/variable.